# Maven plugin for groovy tests

Tags: java, maven, groovy, spock

I have 2 directories for tests:
one for groovy and second for java.
And I'm looking for a maven plugin for run test from a command line. 
I have a plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And it works for Java test, but when I have a not working test in groovy directory maven doesn't show a problem.
It's a structure of my project:

```
    ├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   └── resources
│   └── test
│       ├── groovy
│       └── java
└── target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the official example repository https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example Maven/Gradle/Ant examples.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the gmaven-plugin to your pom e.g.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
   <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>compile</goal>
         <goal>testCompile</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: `gmaven-plugin` seems to be old and deprecated, I'd recommend using `gmavenplus-plugin` instead.